# How to emulate cortex-m linux with qemu?

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, stm32, qemu, cortex-m

this is my code and I want to run it on a cortex-m4 linux based board (stm32f429) but before that I want to test my program on my pc using qemu.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have compiled it with this command : `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static -mcpu=cortex-m4 hello.cpp -o hello` and I checked the generated elf file with `readelf` and this is the output:

```
$ readelf -A hello
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7E-M"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7E-M
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Microcontroller
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

this is how I'm trying to emulate it: `qemu-arm -cpu cortex-m4 hello`

but it throws this error:

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 4 (Illegal instruction) - core dumped
Illegal instruction
```

even when I tryied to run it on my physical board, my kernel throwed `error -8` which is a `ENOEXEC` error or basicaly: `Exec format error`

I tryed it with all cortex-m CPUs but none of them worked (cortex m0, m3, m4, m7)

what is wrong with my elf file? why qemu and my physical board throws this error?